# How can I get a date from SQL Server into Oracle 12c? Dates are being inverted (backwards)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, date

I'm having a real problem getting a date from `SQL Server` into `Oracle` while maintaining the correct value.

The value in SQL Server looks like: `"Apr 28 1969 12:00AM"`
When I pull this value into a `.NET` *DateTime* it looks like: `"04/28/1969 12:00AM"`
When it gets inserted into Oracle it looks like: "28-APR-19"

The Oracle date looks correct at quick glance, but if I do a `TO_CHAR(DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` I get "`04/28/6919`" <---- The year is backwards!!

Here's a set of dates from Oracle:

```
01/18/5919
09/19/8819
02/13/5619
08/30/5819
04/28/6519
08/22/6919
10/24/6119
02/27/6919
02/28/6019
12/20/6219
09/28/3619
10/02/6219
```

All years end in '19' because they are all backwards!

Because Oracle thinks every one of my years ends with "19" it thinks all leap years are invalid and I have a large set of data I can't even get inserted (not to mention the bad dates)

I'm using a simple stored proc to get the data out of SQL Server, the data is then stored in a simple POCO. I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess.OracleBulkCopy` to do my actual insert using the DataTable. I have no control over how I retrieve the data or how I save it... but I can manipulate it in between.

So far I've tried returning the date as a string and doing formatting on it (`dd-MMM-yyyy`) and (`yyyymmdd`) - neither worked. I've also tried setting the date to null if it was a leap year and trying to set it directly afterwards... it's a hack, but that didn't do any good either.

Any help is appreciated.

My stored proc:

> USE [InsuranceFileProcessing]
>   GO
>   SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
>   GO
>   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
>   GO
>   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_GET_INSURANCE_POLICY_HOLDERS_FOR_DATA_UPLOAD]
>          @INSURANCE_COMPANY_CODE VARCHAR(5) 
>        , @INSURANCE_FILE_UPLOAD_LOG_ID  INT
>        , @START_ROW_NUM INT
>        , @END_ROW_NUM INT
>        , @GET_LEAP_YEARS BIT
>   AS 
>   BEGIN 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_NUMBER INT 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY INT 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_STATE INT 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_PROCEDURE NVARCHAR(100) 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_LINE INT 
>       DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY 
          SELECT   DISTINCT                  
              IT.INSURANCE_COMPANY_CODE             INS_COMPANY_NUM
            , IP.POLICY_NUMBER                          INS_POLICY_NUM              
            , PH.FIRST_NAME                             PH_FIRST_NAME
            , PH.MIDDLE_NAME                            PH_MIDDLE_NAME
            , PH.LAST_NAME                              PH_LAST_NAME
            , LEFT(PH.NAME_SUFFIX,1)                    PH_NAME_SUFFIX
            , PH.ADDRESS                                PH_ADDRESS
            , PH.CITY                                   PH_CITY  
            , PH.STATE                                  PH_STATE  
            , PH.ZIPCODE                                PH_ZIP_CODE
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR, PH.DOB, 100)             PH_DATE_OF_BIRTH
            , PH.GENDER                                 PH_GENDER
            , PH.FL_DLN                                 INS_DL_NUMBER               
            , PH.FED_TIN                                INS_FEID
            , PH.FL_DLN_CROSS_REF                       FL_DLN_CROSS_REF
            , PH.FL_DLN_GENERATED                       FL_DLN_GENERATED
            , PH.NON_STRUCTURED_NAME                    PH_NON_STRUCT_NAME  
            , PH.EFFECTIVE_DATE                         EFFECTIVE_DATE      
            , ( CASE PH.COMPANY_INDICATOR 
                WHEN 'Y' THEN 'F'                                   
                WHEN 'N' THEN 'T'
                ELSE 'T'
                END )                                   PERSONAL_FLAG           
            --, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),IP.UPDATE_TS,110)       INSERT_TIMESTAMP    
            , IP.CREATED_TS                             INSERT_TIMESTAMP    
            , IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS                      ROWNUM
            , ph.CUSTOMER_NUMBER                        CUSTOMER_NUMBER


             INTO
                          #UPLOAD_POLICY_HOLDER

            FROM INSURANCE_TRANSACTION IT
                INNER JOIN INSURANCE_COMPANIES IC ON IC.INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID = IT.INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID
                INNER JOIN INSURANCE_POLICY IP ON IT.INSURANCE_POLICY_ID = IP.INSURANCE_POLICY_ID
                INNER JOIN POLICY_HOLDER PH ON IP.INSURANCE_POLICY_ID = PH.INSURANCE_POLICY_ID              
            WHERE IT.INSURANCE_COMPANY_CODE     = @INSURANCE_COMPANY_CODE
                AND IT.INSURANCE_FILE_UPLOAD_LOG_ID  =  @INSURANCE_FILE_UPLOAD_LOG_ID
                AND IT.HAS_ERROR = 0 
                AND PH.HAS_ERROR = 0
                AND ((LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOB, 101), '/', ''), 4) = '0229' AND @GET_LEAP_YEARS = 1)
                    OR (LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOB, 101), '/', ''), 4) <> '0229' AND @GET_LEAP_YEARS = 0))
            ORDER BY  IT.INSURANCE_COMPANY_CODE , IP.POLICY_NUMBER  ;

             SELECT * FROM #UPLOAD_POLICY_HOLDER 
                    WHERE ROWNUM > @START_ROW_NUM AND ROWNUM <= @END_ROW_NUM 
                    ORDER BY ROWNUM;

                    IF EXISTS
                    (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
                    WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#UPLOAD_POLICY_HOLDER')
                    )
                    BEGIN
                          DROP TABLE #UPLOAD_POLICY_HOLDER
                    END


    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

            SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER() 
            SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY() 
            SET @ERROR_STATE = ERROR_STATE() 
            SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
            SET @ERROR_LINE = ERROR_LINE() 
            SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE() 

            EXEC P_INSERT_SQL_ERROR @ERROR_NUMBER, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @ERROR_STATE, @ERROR_PROCEDURE, @ERROR_LINE, @ERROR_MESSAGE 
    END CATCH 

END
```

END

You can ignore the Leap_Year stuff - that was a separate attempt I'd made. The PH.DOB field is the one I'm having issues with. Previously I was just returning the DOB field, the CONVERT() was my attempt to get the value as a string so I could have more control.

My insert into Oracle code:

> private void LoadDataIntoHSMVDBBulk(DataTable dt, string DestinationTableName, List ColumnMappings)
>           {
>               using (var bc = new OracleBulkCopy(GetConnectionString()))
>               {
>                   bc.DestinationTableName = DestinationTableName;
>                   bc.BulkCopyOptions = OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction;

```
            foreach (var colmapping in ColumnMappings)
            {
                var split = colmapping.Split(new[] { ',' });
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add(split.First(), split.Last());
            }

            bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 20000;
            bc.BatchSize = GetOracleBulkCountFromConfig();
            bc.NotifyAfter = GetOracleBulkCountFromConfig();
            bc.OracleRowsCopied += new OracleRowsCopiedEventHandler(bulkCopy_OracleRowsCopied);
            bc.WriteToServer(dt);
            bc.Close();
            bc.Dispose();
            dt.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I took an old copy of our project from several months ago and the dates are correct!! It seems the culprit is our version of the Oracle.DataAccess. When I point to Oracle 11g the dates are good, when I point to the newer Oracle 12c the dates are inverted. Any help is appreciated, but for now we're rolling the servers back to 11g.

Comment: Please show your code to insert into oracle!

Comment: and your code to get that date from sql. Remember, you can always use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Ideally, don't use a string representation *at all*. Fetch as a DateTime, insert as a DateTime...

Comment: Jon - that was what I was doing originally. The string fetching was my attempt at having more control over the format. I'll post my code asap... but there really isn't much to see. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Maybe it's a long shot, but could it be endian difference?

Comment: I don't think it's an endian issue, but I'm not sure how to check that. I was just looking at my data some more and it seems that ALL of my tables which are populated via SQL data have transposed dates for ALL date fields. Seems it's not an issue with my stored proc then, something bigger is going on.

Comment: I just added a few new details. It seems Oracle 12c is causing the problem... Oracle 11g works!

Comment: in Oracle it is best to **specify** format of the date inside the string for Oracle to correctly convert it into date. When converting from String to Date in Oracle you should use `TO_DATE( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )` [full description here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem for us as well and could not resolve it.

We've found workaround though which is not pretty but works. And is not a huge time consumer.
We bulkCopy close and after success we do update on Date type columns. Update should not take too long it is a bulk action.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

```
//EF 5.0.0.
private tables entities = new Tables();
private string validFrom; //try with date as well, should work
private int id;
using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(applicationContext.GetConnection(CrmContext.ConnectionEnum.CrmDatabase)))
{
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE";
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 180;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            bulkCopy.Close();
}
//this is a workaroud due to error in Oracle DataAccess Driver
//look at the
entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET DATE_FROM = TO_DATE(:p0,'DD.MM.YYYY.') WHERE ID = :p1", validFrom, id);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to make sure you're only updating the records you just inserted? I plan to try this out soon - Thanks!